# generating all combintions of a matrix

Tags: php

I am using this code to generate all the combinations in a matrix
but it is not returning output. Can you help me?

```
function combos($data, $all = array(), $group = array(), $val = null,$i=0) {
    if (isset($val)) {
        array_push($group, $val);
    }
    if ($i >= count($data)) {
        array_push($all, $group);
    } else {
        foreach ($data[$i] as $v) {
            combos($data, &$all, $group, $v, $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $all;
}
$data = array(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('d', 'e', 'g'),
    array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z')
);
$combos = combos($data);
print_r($combos);
```

the output should be

```
            0 1 2
array[0]  = a d w
array[1]  = a d x
array[2]  = a d y
array[3]  = a d z
array[4]  = a e w
array[5]  = a e x
array[6]  = a e y
.
.
.
array[23] = b g z
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$all` as `value and not as reference` in your `foreach` loop. Also you are not collecting the returned value of `combos` function in your `foreach` loop.

Modify 
`combos($data, &$all, $group, $v, $i + 1);`

to 
`$all = combos($data, $all, $group, $v, $i + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Capture return value from recursive `combo` function call and remove pass by reference `&$all` from recursive function call.

```
<?php
function combos($data, $all = array(), $group = array(), $val = null, $i = 0)
{
    if (isset($val)) {
        array_push($group, $val);
    }

    if ($i >= count($data)) {
        array_push($all, $group);
    } else {
        foreach ($data[$i] as $v) {
            $all = combos($data, $all, $group, $v, $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $all;
}

$data = array
(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('d', 'e', 'g'),
    array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
);

$combos = combos($data);

print_r($combos);

?>
```

Working example [link](https://eval.in/476742)

Answer (score 0):

Like @PerakSola and @Samir said you may collect returned values of `combos` value or you may pass `$all` variable by reference. To do this in correct way please use this code:

```
function combos($data, &$all = array(), $group = array(), $val = null, $i = 0)
{
    if (isset($val)) {
        array_push($group, $val);
    }

    if ($i >= count($data)) {
        array_push($all, $group);
    } else {
        foreach ($data[$i] as $v) {
            combos($data, $all, $group, $v, $i + 1);
        }
    }
    return $all;
}

$data = array
(
    array('a', 'b'),
    array('d', 'e', 'g'),
    array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'),
);

$combos = combos($data);

print_r($combos);
```